# Why are widget.winfo_rootx() and widget.winfo_rootx() always 0 in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
a = Button(text=str(1))
a.place(x=100, y=100)
widget_x, widget_y = a.winfo_rootx(), a.winfo_rooty()
print(widget_x, widget_y)
root.mainloop()
```

The output is always `0 0`. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value is zero because you're getting the coordinates before the window has been made visible. You can solve this one of two ways: don't get the coordinates until after mainloop has started (with `after_idle`), or force the window to be drawn to the screen by calling `update`.

Example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
a = Button(text=str(1))
a.place(x=100, y=100)

root.update()
widget_x, widget_y = a.winfo_rootx(), a.winfo_rooty()
print(widget_x, widget_y)

root.mainloop()
```