# How can I get the current grid position of a Tkinter object like a Label?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, math, tkinter

I have a tkinter object:

```
label_test = Label(window_main, text="label_test")
```

i have tried but this outputs 0 every time

```
label_test_position_y = label_test.winfo_rooty()
label_test_position_x = label_test.winfo_rootx()
```

This outputs the x & y but how can I get which grid position it is in(column =1, row=1)

I would like to get the position of this label and be able to print it out(I have to do math with this number, because other tkinter objects will be placed on screen depending on this number).
Thank you. I will edit any code that I need to, to help anyone help me. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are widget.winfo\_rootx() and widget.winfo\_rootx() always 0 in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50667026/why-are-widget-winfo-rootx-and-widget-winfo-rootx-always-0-in-tkinter)

Comment: Oh okay thank you @JohnColeman I'll check it out!

Comment: It is possible that your issue is different than in that other question. If so, please provide a [mcve] to give additional details.

Comment: No that kind of solves my issue. it did answer my question, but now there is a new question, I was hoping since I was using grid it might output the grid value(for math I need it) but it was a long shot. If you know how to get the column & row that would be helpful too. This did answer my question and I may be able to work with this.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm using x and y now for placement and its working at better. This works thank you! If you post an answer I'll mark it

Comment: Glad it helped you. I voted to close it as a duplicate, so I won't post the comment as an answer. If you have another question, ask it in a new question, but it sounds like you have figured things out.